# Qiskit job not giving the right result after execution

Tags: qiskit, programming

Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import qiskit
from qiskit import *


number_of_qubits = 3
backend_sim = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')

#Generate a circuit in qiskit
input_circuit = QuantumCircuit(number_of_qubits, number_of_qubits)
input_circuit.x(0)
input_circuit.h(1)
input_circuit.cx(0,1)
input_circuit.i(1) 
input_circuit.x(1)

job_sim = execute(input_circuit, backend_sim, shots=1024)
result_sim = job_sim.result()
counts = result_sim.get_counts(input_circuit)
print(counts)
```

No matter what gates I try (e.g. I can remove the last X gate), the result is always `'000': 1024`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current circuit looks like this:

[image: example circuit without measurements]

In order to get the "counts", you need to measure at the end of the circuit, before `execute`.

```
input_circuit.measure(range(number_of_qubits), range(number_of_qubits))
```

[image: Example circuit with measurements]

Comment: Ah, makes sense! Thank you!